# JPA Using sequences as auto increment postgres

Tags: postgresql, jpa, sequence

I have this code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
@SequenceGenerator(name="table_id_seq", sequenceName="table_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
public class TableExample extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     * The auto-generated primary key.
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="table_id_seq")
    @Column(name = "table_id")
    private long id;
}
```

And I have this SEQUENCE in my database:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table_id_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 2000
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE table_id_seq OWNER TO postgres;
```

When I am trying to persist a new object, I get this error:

> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: ERROR: current
>   transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction
>   block {prepstmnt 642363 SELECT NEXTVAL('table_id_seq')} [code=0,
>   state=25P02]

Am I missing something??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The error arose before that code; there's another problem earlier else that caused the transaction to be aborted. Examine your PostgreSQL server error logs or Hibernate/JPA logs to see where the FIRST error occurred, that'll be the real problem.